# Is elixir out-dated?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, python-elixir

My sqlalchemy is 0.6.3, and elixir is 0.7.1

I created a model class which extends `Entity`:

```
from elixir import *
class User(Entity):
    pass
```

And save the a user as:

```
user = User()
user.save()
```

It reports `Session has no attribute 'save'`

I looked into the code of elixir, found it invokes `sqlalchemy.org.session.Session#save()`, but there is no `save()` method there.

So, is `elixir` outdated, and we should not use it any more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using the same versions of SQLAlchemy and Elixir so it is definitely compatible. Not sure what you are trying to do with the above code.

Comment: How do you save an entity? `entity.save()` will throw exception, and `session.add(entity)` will also throw exception.

Answer (score 1):

Remember to call setup_all(True) before doing anything with session or query. This will do the necessary ORM mappings for the session and the query to work properly.